How should I connect my ceiling light fixture wires?
I live in Europe and just moved into an old house. I am trying to install a ceiling lamp. The lamp has one blue and one black wire. The ceiling has 3 wires; two are black and one is green/yellow.
The two black wires are loose while the green/yellow one is attached to a piece which has three individual holes. Each hole has 2 screws so that you can connect the wires through it and tighten.

It seems like the 2 black wires are the neutral and a switched live, which should have a red sleeve applied.
It may well be that the red sleeve has been lost, or for some jurisdictions, not needed.
So, either find out which one is switched and connect the brown to it - adding a red sleeve or red tape to the black wire,
Or, just connect the 2 black wires to the brown and blue of the ceiling lamp, this will be ok if the ceiling lamp does not have a metal body. If it does then you need to find the switched black and connect the brown to that.
The green/yellow is the earth and should be connected to the terminal with markings like:


Thank you very much! I’ll go ahead and try it this way
